# Grouping a large set of ReactDOM.render() calls in a root component

Tags: javascript, data-structures, reactjs, functional-programming, reactive-programming

Let's say I have a large HTML document with numerous React Components embedded in parts of it.

For example:

```
<body>

    <h1 id="react-component-1">...</h1>
    <p>Static Content</p>

    <h2> id="react-component-2">...</h2>
    <img src="static-img" />
    <p id="react-component-3">...</h3>

</body>
```

As you can see, there are static elements in-between my dynamic elements. I'd imagine that this situation is common in web sites that are slowly bringing React in to there toolchain.

Right now my application works like this:

```
function renderPage(data) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Component {...data} />, document.getElementById("react-component-1"));
    ReactDOM.render(<Component {...data} />, document.getElementById("react-component-2"));
    ReactDOM.render(<Component {...data} />, document.getElementById("react-component-3"));
}
```

`renderPage()` is called upon the success of an ajax request. This makes my components update as intended, and it seems pretty performant.

However, it would be much nicer if I had a root React component that handled the state of the application, and pushed down changes to `data` as props.

I can't make a root component though because not everything on my page is dynamic, I need to preserve the static content in-between the React components.

I would love to be able to do something like this though:

```
class Root extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.data = {...};
     }

    render() {
        ReactDOM.render(<Component {...this.state.data} />, document.getElementById("react-component-1"));
        ReactDOM.render(<Component {...this.state.data} />, document.getElementById("react-component-2"));
        ReactDOM.render(<Component {...this.state.data} />, document.getElementById("react-component-3"));        
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is it possible to use React this way? At first I unsure of how it would be possible, because ReactDOM expects an element to render components in to, which would clear out my static content when I render my root component. Now I am thinking I could just do `new Root()`, but I have yet to test this.

Another option that I just thought of was keeping the `renderPage()` function and calling it ONCE instead of every time AJAX is loaded. Each component would then listen for a custom event that is fired on the AJAX success, which contains the new data. This seems slower though... And I might as well use Redux for the application state.

Comment: this is not the right way to approach react, the whole point is that you have modular components you can use over and over. You should think about what types of components you have, h1, h2, & p from the above as separate components, once you have that passing in static data as props is the way to go. Check this out: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: i am aware of how React is intended to be used. There's no indication that inflexible or redundant components exist in my example code. You are missing the point unfortunately. The use-case here is that not all content on the page can be React. There are many elements that aren't going to be dynamic in nature, but I would like to wrap everything in a root level component so that I can leverage the component lifecycle to refresh the props of my dynamic elements.

Comment: Umm, thats exactly what I said...put the non dynamic stuff in the react component....you dont have to use props, you can just put the content in as you like: exactly like the answer below. It's not a cross roads, its how its done. Its the best practice for what you are asking for. And like the answer points out, your in for a world of hurt if this thing grows and you have to change it.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my original comment, thats on me, my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `render` method of a React component to call `ReactDOM.render` the way you do it in your example `Root` component. The `render` method of a component can return either a valid React element (for example, `<div />`) or `null` and is not supposed to do any mutations, such as modifying the DOM, etc. If a React component needs to do some DOM mutations, it should do it from lifecycle hooks such as `ComponentDidMount` or `ComponentDidUpdate`.

To answer you question, it depends whether your static content, can be included in a React component or not.

**If you can**, which would be ideal, you can refactor your code to have a `Root` component like so :

```js
class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Component data={ this.props.data } />
            <p>Static Content</p>
            <Component data={ this.props.data } />
            <img src="static-img" />
            <Component data={ this.props.data } />
        );
    }
}
```

and to have one call to `ReactDOM.render` :

```
ReactDOM.render(<Root data={ data } />, document.getElementById('my-react-mounting-point'));
```

**If you cannot**, that is if you *need* to have different React render trees, your current approach is fine. If you do this, though, be careful to call `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode` when you do not need the component anymore, or you might face memory leak issues. This [article from React's blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html) has several nice tips about the precautions to use when having various render trees + a `ReactComponentRenderer` boilerplate to avoid common pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is the crossroads I found myself in. It would be a lot of extra work to rebuild the static content as JSX. I was a little worried about calling ReactDOM.render() multiple times on the same components, but it seems as though it's working fine and leveraging the Virtual DOM as intended to diff what needs to be replaced.

Comment: @lostPixels ok. I've added a link with some React tips about it